# For loop confusion

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, compound-assignment

I have :

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int main(void) { 
int s,i,t[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }; 
s = 1; 
for(i = 2; i < 6 ; i += i + 1) 
s += t[i]; 
printf("%d",s); 
return 0; 
}
```

Why is the result 8?

What I'm thinking:

```
first loop: 2<6 True
i+=i+1 is 5
s=1+t[5] =>1+5=6
second loop : 5<6 True
i=5+5+2=11
s=6+t[11]???
```

Comment: Why don't you update `s` during first loop iteration?

Comment: You seem to expect the `i += i + 1` part is executed before the loop body is executed. It is not. It is only executed afterwards, right before the condition is checked again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will guide you to the `for` loop [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/for):

> iteration-expression is evaluated after the loop body and its result
> is discarded. After evaluating iteration-expression, control is
> transferred to cond-expression.

In your example, `i += i + 1`, which is the iteration expression we're talking about, is evaluated after the loop body.

Taking this into account, the result will be 8

Answer (score 2):

The loop increment expression (`i += i + 1` in your case) happens *after* the loop body, not before.

So in the first iteration you do

```
s = 1 + t[2];
```

---

More generally, any `for` loop could be expressed as a `while` loop:

```
for (a; b; c)
{
    d;
}
```

is equivalent to

```
{
    a;
    while (b)
    {
        {
            d;
        }
        c;
    }
}
```

For your specific case it's:

```
{
    i = 2;
    while (i < 6)
    {
        {
            s += t[i]; 
        }

        i += i + 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Look attentively at the third expression in the for loop

```
s = 1; 
for(i = 2; i < 6 ; i += i + 1) 
s += t[i];
```

It is `i += i + 1`. So in iterations of the loop the variable `i` will be changed the following way

```
i = 2 (initially)
i = 5 ( i += i + 1 => i += 2  + 1 => i += 3 => i = 2 + 3)
```

After the second iteration of the loop the variable `i` will be already greater than `6`. (i += i + 1 => i += 5 + 1 => i += 6 => i = 5 + 6)

So this statement

```
s += t[i];
```

in fact produces the following sum

```
1 + t[2] + t[5] = 1 + 2 + 5
```

that is equal to `8`.